# Antlr4 picks up wrong tokens and rules

Tags: c#, antlr4

I have something that goes alongside:

```
method_declaration : protection? expression identifier LEFT_PARENTHESES (method_argument (COMMA method_argument)*)? RIGHT_PARENTHESES method_block;

expression
    : ...
    | ...
    | identifier
    | kind
    ;

identifier : IDENTIFIER ;
kind : ... | ... | VOID_KIND; // void for example there are more

IDENTIFIER : (LETTER | '_') (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')*;
VOID_KIND : 'void';

fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z];
fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
```

*The other rules on the `method_declaration` are not relavent for this question

What happens is that when I input something such as `void Start() { }`
and look at the ParseTree, it seems to think `void` is an `identifier` and not a `kind`, and treats it as such.

I tried changing the order in which `kind` and `identifier` are written in the `.g4` file... but it doesn't quite seem to make any difference... why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Antlr will not output any error message for `VOID_KIND` because the token name has a lexer rule defining it. The RHS of rule `IDENTIFIER` is not a string literal, so there is no check for overlap of `VOID_KIND` against it (presumably expense to check). However, if there were two lexer rules that have the same RHS string literal, e.g., `K: 'k'; Q: 'k';`, then the tool would output `One of the token Q values unreachable. k is always overlapped by token K`. _Always print the token stream. For C#, make sure to use Antlr4.Runtime.Standard and Antlr4BuildTasks, not old unsupported Antlr4.Runtime._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which parser rules are defined makes no difference in ANTLR. The order in which token rules are defined does though. Specifically, when multiple token rules match on the current input and produce a token of the same length, ANTLR will apply the one that is defined first in the grammar.

So in your case, you'll want to move `VOID_KIND` (and any other keyword rules you may have) before `IDENTIFIER`. So pretty much what you already tried except with the lexer rules instead of the parser rules.

PS: I'm somewhat surprised that ANTLR doesn't produce a warning about `VOID_KIND` being unmatchable in this case. I'm pretty sure other lexer generators would produce such a warning in cases like this.

Comment: OMG I forgot about Lexer Rules.. You're right! And no Antlr did not write any warning whatsoever. Thank you!

Comment: ANTLR has a problem identifying the 2 rules overlap. When `IDENTIFIER` would look like: `IDENTIFIER : 'void' | (LETTER | '_') (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')*;` then the following warning is produced: `One of the token VOID_KIND values unreachable. void is always overlapped by token IDENTIFIER`